# Why are many answers posted as comments?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have noted that many questions appear to have 0 answers, when there are several answers given as comments.  What is the exact protocol for when an answer should be posted as an answer (or not)?

Comment: Maybe this is a question for Meta.

Comment: Answers posted as comments imply the question was not deep enough, nor the "solution" deep enough to warrant a the title of a full answer.  This does, admittedly, mislead some solvers who go to questions that have been already solved.

Comment: Go to Meta and search "Posting answers in comments". Some good answers there. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks to MathLind. This was helpful.

Comment: Yup, as David Stork mentioned, usually if a question is easily answered by reading the documentation, or is due to a simple mistake, or is really easy, or is badly/vaguely formulated, then it is answered in comments (and then subsequently closed). The reason for this is StackExchange mechanics: if a non-useful question is answered, then it will not be auto-deleted even if it is closed, and thus remains on the site forever. Thus, to uphold site quality, users avoid responding via answers, and instead use comments.